# Hatcher: length of Infinite paths in infinite graphs?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, algebraic-topology

Hatcher begin with:

> Proposition 1A.1:
> Every connected graph contains a maximal tree, and in fact, any
> tree in the graph is contained in a maximal tree.

Then goes on to define a "height function $h: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$, where he says:

> The structure of trees can be elucidated by looking more closely at the
> constructions in the proof of Proposition 1A.1. If X is a tree and $v_0$ is any vertex of $X$ , then the
> construction of a maximal tree $Y \subseteq X$ starting with $Y_0 = \{ v_0 \}$
> yields an increasing sequence of subtrees $Y_n \subseteq X$ whose union is
> all of $X$ since a tree has only one maximal subtree, namely itself.
> We can think of the vertices in $Y_n − Y_{n−1}$ as being at ‘height’ $n$ ,
> with the edges of $Y_n − Y_{n−1}$ connecting these vertices to vertices
> of height $n − 1$ . In this way we get a ‘height function’ $h : X  \rightarrow \mathbb R$
> assigning to each vertex its height, and monotone on edges.

I don't understand why a path must be *finite*. We can have an infinite tree that has infinite paths. If so, why will the height function $h: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a legal function?
Hatcher explais:

> For each vertex $v$ of $X$ there is exactly one edge leading downward from $v$ , so
> by following these downward edges we obtain a path from $v$ to the base vertex $v_0$ .
> This is an example of an edgepath, which is a **composition of finitely many paths** each
> consisting of a single edge traversed monotonically

Why is this the case? I can definitely create a connected infinite graph $G$, for example, the graph with vertices as natural numbers $V = \mathbb N$ with edge set $E \equiv \{ (n, n+ 1) : n \in \mathbb N \}$. This has the infinite path $0, 1, 2, \dots$  So why is the height function finite?

More broadly, I don't understand whether Hatcher's constructions are supposed to work only with finite graphs (If so, he seems to be going through a lot of trouble instead of appealing to finiteness), or they should work with infinite graphs (but don't seem to work!)

Comment: I believe the confusion is that a path between two vertices must be finite not that there can't be infinite paths. The height function assigns a value to the vertices.

Comment: @aldodecristo Why can't we have an infinite path between two vertices?

Comment: because it wouldn't be connected. Given two vertices $u$ and $v$ you would have a sequence of vertices and edges that starts with $u$ then either at some finite point it reaches $v$ or it goes on forever. if it goes on forever there is no last element to the sequence to connect to $v$ or to another sequence

Comment: sorry for the double comment but I was introduced to graph theory after studying ordinals and was perplexed by this same thing here is another question on MSE that might help:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39590/infinite-paths-that-connect-two-vertices

Comment: @SiddharthBhat what's an infinite path between two vertices anyway? How would you define such thing? For example your $0,1,2,\ldots$ path: what vertices does it connect? It does not have end. Even if there is a way to define it (which seems odd at least), Hatcher (and almost everyone) definitely talks about finite paths only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph is assumed connected. This means **by definition** that there is a path $v_1 = v, \dotsc, v_n = w$ between any pair of vertices $v, w.$ Notice that a path is finite *by definition*. Indeed, what would it mean that you can get from your house to the store in an infinite number of steps? Why, it would mean that you could NOT get there. It is true that there are infinite paths, but their existence is irrelevant for this.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I wish Hatcher had included that this was the _definition_ of a path!