# Vertex sets separated only by infinitely many vertices imply an infinite number of disjoint paths between them.

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity, infinite-graphs

In Reinhard Diestel's book "Graph Theory" (5th ed.) there is a chapter on infinite graphs (chapter 8).

In that chapter Diestel states the following fact related to Menger's Theorem:

> **Proposition 8.4.1** Let $G$ be any graph, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and let $A, B$ be two sets of vertices in $G$ that can be separated by $k$ but no fewer than $k$ vertices. Then $G$ contains $k$ disjoint $A-B$ paths.

Directly below the proof of that proposition, he states:

> When k is inﬁnite, however, the result suddenly becomes trivial.

I interpret this as the following reformulation of the Proposition:

> If two vertex sets $A$, $B$ of an (infinite) graph $G$ can not be separated by finitely many vertices, then $G$ contains infinitely many disjoint $A$-$B$ paths.

He then argues why that is:

> Let $\mathcal{P}$ be any maximal set of disjoint $A-B$ paths in $G$. Then the union of all these paths separates $A$ from $B$, so $\mathcal{P}$ must be infinite.
> But then the cardinality of this union is no bigger than $|\mathcal{P}|$. Thus, $\mathcal{P}$ contains $|\mathcal{P}| = | \bigcup \mathcal{P} | \geq k$ disjoint $A-B$ paths, as desired.

I do not understand why we can immediately conclude that $\mathcal{P}$ is infinite in the second sentence. What if the number of disjoint $A-B$ paths is finite, but some of the paths are infinite? Then $\bigcup \mathcal{P}$ still contains an infinite number of vertices, including those which separate $A$ and $B$.

For example, there could be a non-disjoint set $\mathcal{Q}$ of $A-B$ paths that have an infinite number of distinct intersection vertices with some infinite paths of $\mathcal{P}$ while still only intersecting with finitely many paths of $\mathcal{P}$ in total.

I have been thinking about this for quite a long time and I suppose I am just missing some really obvious fact here. Maybe I should also point out that I have very little experience with infinite graphs and am still learning the basics of graph theory.

Maybe you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think paths with endpoints are of finite length by definition.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39590/infinite-paths-that-connect-two-vertices

Comment: @Yorch Are you saying that if a path has a beginning and an end, then that path contains finitely many vertices? But many paths of containing a non-finite number of vertices have a first vertex and a last vertex. For example, suppose that $P$ is a path defined as follows: The first vertex of $P$ is the number $0$. The last vertex of $P$ is the number $1$. $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ if $0 \leq x < 1$, $x$ is a node in path $P$ and the node appearing immediately after $x$ is $x + \dfrac{1}{10^{min\{k \in \mathbb{N}: \quad \mathtt{FLOOR}(10^{k} * (x - \mathtt{FLOOR}(x))) \neq 10^{k}-1\}}}$

Comment: @Yorch My previous comment was wrong. I was wrong about every real number between $0$ and $1$ being a node. Some examples of function $S$ being evaluated are as follows: $S(0) = \frac{1}{10}$ and . Also, we have $S(0.4990) = 0.5990$ and $S(0.992) = 0.993$

Comment: When I tried to come up with a counterexample I considered a sequence that converges to $0$ on $[0,1)$ and one that converges to $2$ on $(1,2]$, and joining them to form a $0,2$ path, but that isn't "connected". I think the answer is just that Diestel is almost automatically assuming $u-v$ paths are finite, which I (from my limited point of view) is completley ok. @SamuelMuldoon