# Infinite "connected" graphs and spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, trees

Let us say that graph $G$ is *quasi-connected* iff for every two vertices there is either a finite path or an infinite path in sense of the offtopic of this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1725369/155134).

Assuming the axiom of choice, is it true that every quasi-connected graph has a "spanning tree" (that is a subgraph where every pair of vertices is connected by unique finite or infinite path)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

First choose an infinite ray in each of the (ordinarily) connected components, and extend it to a spanning tree.

Then, as long as there is still a subgraph isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ anywhere in the graph, select one of its edges and remove it. At some point (after possibly transfinitely many edge removals) you cannot remove more edges, and the graph is now a forest of trees with exactly one infinite branch each.

And a "tree" in the sense you define in your final parenthesis is exactly either an ordinary tree, or a forest of ordinary trees that each have exactly one infinite branch. To connect two nodes in different components you need to go from each of the nodes out the infinite branch of its component, and then connect those two rays at infinity.

Comment: What do you mean by "a subgraph isomorphic to Z"? And "infinite branch" is "infinite path" or a ray in sense of the linked answer?

Comment: @byk7: $\mathbb Z$ is here shorthand for the graph that has a vertex for each integer and an edge between each integer and it successor. -- An "infinite path" _is_ the same as a ray in the sense of the linked answer.

Comment: By a "tree with exactly one infinite branch" I mean a tree where you can choose a root node and there will be exactly one ray starting at that node. (This implies that if you choose a _different_ node there will also be exactly one ray starting at _that_ node).

Comment: Ok, thx. One more thing -- if you want to connect two rays, why they cannot be "separated forever" (like they are going in "opposite" directions or so)?

Comment: @byk7: No, by "connect two rays", I mean at the infinite ends, like what the linked answer described as "essentially the only new type of path that we gain from this generalisation". The generalisation _has no concept of_ infinite rays going "in different directions" -- _any two_ (disjoint) infinite rays may be joined in this way according to the proposed generalization of "path".

Comment: @hmakholmleftoverMonica For the second step (edge removal): how do you make sure this process terminates? I think I can prove it with Zorn's lemma if the graph is locally finite (i.e. every vertex has finite degree), but my proof does not seem to work in general.