# Can there be an uncountable connected graph with only countable degrees?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If each vertex in a connected graph is connected to only countably many vertices, then does that mean there are only countably many vertices in the graph?

Comment: What's your definition of "connected" for an uncountable graph? That any two vertices can be joined by a finite path?

Comment: Vertices $a$ and $b$ are connected iff there exists a set $S$ of pairs of vertices such that $(v,w) \in S$ $w \neq b \implies \exists w' \in V: (w, w') \in S$ and $v \neq a \implies \exists v' \in V: (v', v) \in S$.

Comment: That doesn't seem to match the definition of connectivity in the finite case. What if we just take the graph $\{a,b,c,d\}$ with edges $E = \{(c,d),(d,c)\}$. Doesn't $S=E$ fit the bill for $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Yes, oops. Adding "and $\exists v \in V: (a,v) \in S$ and $\exists v \in V: (v,b) \in S$" should fix it.

Comment: Alright. What about two chains $(a_1, a_2, a_3, ...)$ and $(b_1, b_2, b_3, ...)$ which have no edges between them. Is $a_1$ connected to $b_1$?

Comment: @Sambo: If they're infinite, then my definition would imply they would be... But that seems wrong. Is there even a way to define two vertices connected by an infinite path that makes sense then?

Comment: bof links an interesting question in the comments of the answer below. I don't have an answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you just need a very long chain.  As long as your definition of a path allows uncountable lengths, just take $\omega_2$ with each element connected to the one above, the one below, the one $\omega$ above, the one $\omega$ below, the one $\omega_1$ above and the one $\omega_1$ below (if they exist).  Take the connected component that includes $1$.  Starting from $1$ you can add uncountably many $\omega_1$s.

The standard definition of a path is that it is finite and the definition of a connected component is that every vertex is connected to every other by a path.  In that case the answer is yes.  Start from any vertex and close under the path operation.  As each step in the path has countably many branches you have a countable union of countable sets, which is countable.

Comment: Of course a connected graph, in which every vertex has countable degree, must be countable. I guess your answer must be based on the OP's weird definition of "connected" in the comments. That's fine, but please include the definition of "connected" in your answer, because I didn't understand the OP's definition.

Comment: @bof:  as I read OP's definition an uncountable chain is acceptable because you can have uncountably many pairs of vertices in the definition of the graph and a path.  That supports my answer.  If you can't have an uncountable chain my answer fails.

Comment: The standard definition of connected graph (finite or infinite, countable or uncountable) is, any two vertices are connected by a finite path. If a nonstandard definition is being used, that definition should appear in either the question or the answer. It is unsatisfactory to have an essential part of the question appear only in comments, which are evanescent.

Comment: Note that, in the OP's definition, the elements of $S$ are just pairs of vertices, nobody says they are edges of the graph. And even if we assume the OP meant to say that $S$ is a set of edges, the definition still doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Note that, if $G=(V,E)$ with no isolated vertices (for example, an uncountable $1$-regular graph) then $G$ is "connected" according to the bizarre definition in the OP's comments; the set $S=E$ satisfies all of the stated conditions.

Comment: @Stefan:  please look at the comments from bof and review your definition of connected.  I think my answer is in the spirit of your question.  When I look at the great source Wikipedia there is nothing that makes paths be finite.  If paths must be finite or even countable the answer changes.

Comment: **Of course** a path may be infinite. But a path with two endpoints has to be finite. Anyway, a connected graph has a **finite** path between any two vertices. We can avoid confusion (well, we can **try**) by defining connected graph without mentioning paths: the graph is connected if it is not possible to partition the vertex set into two nonempty sets with no edge from one to the other.

Comment: Anyway, although I'm not impressed by the OP's attempted definition of "connected graph", I'm not asking anybody to **change** it. All I ask is that a clear statement of the idiosyncratic definition you're using be **edited into the question or the answer,** rather than buried in the comments, or scattered across several comments.

Comment: See the answers to the top Related Question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39360/infinite-shortest-paths-in-graphs

Comment: This example is wrong. The connected component you're looking at is $\{a\omega_1+b\omega+c\}$ with $a,b,c$ nonnegative integers, a countable set. And that's in the strongest possible sense; there are no edges from anywhere inside this set to anywhere outside it.

Comment: @jmerry:  that assumes paths must be finite.  One can certainly define a graph that has an uncountable chain of pairs $(a,b), (b,c),(c,d)\ldots$.  In my quick look I didn't see a requirement that a path be finite and that was the point of my first sentence.  I will add in a note that the standard definition of path is finite and that the answer is then yes.

Comment: A path doesn't have to be finite, but it must be countable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are only countably many vertices in a connected graph in which each vertex has countable degree.

I'll actually prove this in a slightly different form. Let $A$ be a graph with vertex set $V$ and $v$ be a vertex. There is a countable set $S\subset V$ such that there are no edges between $S$ and $V\setminus S$. This is essentially based on the topological definition of connectedness; we say a graph is connected if it cannot be split into two nonempty sets of vertices with no edges between them.
To do this, we construct $S$ directly. Let $S_0=\{v\}$, $S_1=\{u\ \mid\ (u,v)\in A\}$ (the set of everything directly connected to $v$), and continue inductively: $S_n=\{u\ \mid\ (u,w)\in A\text{ for some }w\in S_{n-1}\}$. Each $S_n$ is countable, since $S_{n-1}$ is countable and thus only countably many edges have a vertex in it. Let $S =\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} S_n$. This is a countable union of countable sets, hence countable. Since every edge with one vertex in $S_n$ has its other in $S_{n+1}$, every edge with one vertex in $S$ has its other in $S$. Done.